# Duvida sobre asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, framework

O framework 4 suporta o MVC 5 ? Pois tenho um site que está em mvc 5 e o iis 6 não está abrindo o site, após clicar em entrar na tela de login a página fica em branco.
Vi que o iis 6 não suporta o framework 4.5, então converti pro 4.0.
O que posso fazer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não rola, ASP.NET MVC 5 requer o .NET 4.5.
A versão 4.0 só suporta MVC 4.

Comment: Entendi @Ivan Teles, sabe como posso converter pro mvc 4 ?

Comment: Rapaz realizar downgrade, na verdade nunca precisei.

Comment: rsrs, é eu também até agora. O cara que desenvolveu o site aqui acho que não sabia que o iis 6 não suportava framework 4.5, ai to tendo esse trabalho de voltar pro 4.0 e o mvc também.

Comment: Creio que vc pode desistalar o MVC5 via nuget e instalar o 4, dai vc vai consertando os problemas que surgirem.

Comment: Sabe como desinstalo mvc 5 via nuget ?

Comment: UiInstall-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 5.2.3, em 5.2.3 vc informa a versão instalada.

Comment: Puta cara, aqui na empresa tá bloqueando. E agora ?